# Rails 3.1 Unable to run Ajax call

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Issue I am facing is that my ajax call is not placing the data to my page, I guess somehow Ajax is still not enabled, I might be doing something foolish, need guidance
code in **index.html.erb**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/abc.css" />

 <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></sc`enter code here`ript>
 <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/malls.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  <%= link_to "Home", {:action => "AjaxView`"} , :update =>  "Ajaxcall" , :remote => true %>

  <div id="Ajaxcall">This should change</div>
```

Code in **app_controller**

```
def AjaxView
  render :layout => false
end
```

Code in **AjaxView.html.erb**

```
 Hello from Ajax
```

I have also copied prototype.js and scriptaculous.js at public\javascripts
and updated **application_controller.html.erb**

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

At console I am getting following:

```
Started GET "/malls/AjaxView" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-04 15:23:13 +0530
Processing by MallsController#AjaxView as JS
Rendered malls/AjaxView.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Things look fine, but still my ajax text is not getting updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax in rails does not work that way, The Ajaxview controller should render ajaxview.js.erb file. 
The file should contain javascript to update your DOM in index.html.erb. Hope this helps.